# (Co)homology of HNN extensions

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group with a subgroup $A$, and let $\varphi:A\rightarrow G$ be any injection. The HNN extension with base $G$ and associated subgroups $A$ and $\varphi(A)$ is defined as $$G^{\ast}=\langle\; S_{G},\; t\;|\;R_{G},\;t^{-1}at=\varphi(a),\;a\in A\;\rangle,$$
where $\langle\; S_{G}\;|\;R_{G}\;\rangle$ is a presentation for $G$.

Is there any method or theorem that one could use to compute the (co)homology of $G^{\ast}$?

Comment: I don't know...but have you looked in Ken Brown's book?

Comment: If you have a $K(G,1)$ and a $K(A,1)$, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (Section 1.B) gives a construction of a $K(G^*,1)$ using mapping cylinders.  You may be able to use that to compute the cohomology.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi,\psi: A\to G$ be two embeddings of a group $A$ to a group $G$ and denote by $G^*$ the corresponding HNN-extension. Robert Bieri in [his article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01187054) proved that  for any $G^*$-module $M$ there are long exact sequences for homology
$$
 \to H_n(A,M) \to H_n(G,M) \to H_n(G^*,M) \to H_{n-1}(A,M) \to 
$$
and cohomology
$$
\to H^n(G^*,M) \to H^n(G,M) \to H^n(A,M) \to H^{n+1}(G^*,M) \to
$$